# Declaring private variable inside Main

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        private int panda=3;            
    }
}
```

Compiler spits 4 errors when I do this. Declaring private variable in main is forbidden? Why?

Comment: C# does not allow declaring private variables inside method, as all variables inside method are private

Comment: Main is a method and not a class

Comment: What do you expect to be the meaning of _private_ inside a method?

Comment: I wanted to make it because i did not want that variable name to mix with other class variables.

Comment: Don`t worry about that,it will be private in scope declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared inside a block (i.e. code between two curly braces) are only visible inside this block, so there is no sense in declaring them private, public or protected.

```
Class A
{
private static int x=0;//make sense

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       private static int x=0; //does not make sense
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your private is inside a method not a class.

```
class Program
{
    private static int panda=3;            
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the MSDN that says:

> The private keyword is a member access modifier. Private access is the
>   least permissive access level. **Private members are accessible only
>   within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared**

you can not define a variable as `Private` inside a method. Logically, declaring a variable as `Private` inside method does not make a sense.

Referense: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's cause it's a local variable (local to the function `Main` and not accessible by any other method/procedure unless passed explicitley) and not a class member. It just should be

```
int panda=3;
```

Or if you meant to be class member then declare it in class scope.

```
class Program
{
    private int panda=3;
```